# Microsoft Teams TASK module SSO is returning `Definition not found` error

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are getting `Definition not found` error while calling `msTeams.authentication.getAuthToken` in @microsoft/teams-js from the task module.

- **@microsoft/teams-js** version - 1.7.0 and 1.11.0
- **Environment** - Desktop and Mobile

```js
return new Observable<any>(subscriber => {
      this.teamsService.authentication.getAuthToken({
        resources: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/openid',
          'https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read.all',
          'https://graph.microsoft.com/group.read.all',
          'https://graph.microsoft.com/groupmember.read.all'],
        successCallback: clientToken => {
          subscriber.next({ clientToken, type: this.authType });
          subscriber.complete();
        },
        failureCallback: reason => {
          subscriber.error(reason);
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: This is already a known bug and engineering team is working on it. I don't have an ETA or public URL to share as it is internal but I will update you as soon as it is fixed.

Comment: Wanted to confirm one thing are you facing this issue while opening task module with Deep link? Was that used to work earlier?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT Thanks for the quick response, yes we are trying to open the task module with a deep link and it was working earlier and suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Thanks for the update, bug is already raised I will let you know once it is fixed.

Comment: @RiteshThakkar: Are you using Manifest app id in deep link?   If yes, copy the app id from Teams admin center and use for deep link to fix the issue.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft - we are working on that and will get back to you soon.